# Why use SMTP Authentication

Tags: php, security, email-spam

Why should i use a mailer class like PHPMailer instead of the simple PHP `mail` function?
Is there security problem or spam danger?

The only reason why i don't want to use PHPMailer is that the mail password is displayed in the source code. Using the simple `mail` function i avoid this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With PHPMailer you can work better with headers, html mails, etc. The mail function is the basic way.

Any way i suggest you [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) is have a better support and is a bit more modern.

Answer (score 0):

```
PHPMailer is a PHP class for PHP (www.php.net) that provides a package of functions to send email. The two primary features are sending HTML Email and e-mails with attachments. PHPMailer supports nearly all possiblities to send email: mail(), Sendmail, qmail & direct to SMTP server. You can use any feature of SMTP-based e-mail, multiple recepients via to, CC, BCC, etc. In short: PHPMailer is an efficient way to send e-mail within PHP.

As you may know, it is simply to send mails with the PHP mail() function. So why use PHPMailer? Isn't it slower? Yes that's true, but PHPMailer makes it easy to send e-mail, makes it possible to attach files, send HTML e-mail, etc. With PHPMailer you can even use your own SMTP server and avoid Sendmail routines used by the mail() function on Unix platforms. 

Reference:
http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/wiki/UsefulTutorial
```